# Why won't the scene pause?

Tags: swift, scenekit

I am trying to pause my scene when my SCNPyramid reaches a certain coordinate to setup my tutorial for game. However, the scene never pauses and I am not sure why.

```
if (leftSpike5.position.x == 0.4) {
        self.isPaused = true
    }
```

Comment: Does this code get executed? Can you put a breakpoint or `print` statement there?

Comment: @jtbandes the reason might be because it doesn't start at 0.4. It contains a moveBy action and when it hits that position I want the scene to pause. I tested it by putting if (leftSpike5.position.x  < 0.4) { self.isPaused = true } and the scene will pause but checking the node at a position does not work.

Comment: Welcome to floating point arithmetic! You'll almost always need to do a < or > comparison instead of ==. In lieu of pausing the scene when the threshold is met, you might also consider using  an `SCNAction` to move your pyramid, and then proceed with the tutorial when the action finishes.